# intermittent error from rally 'Not authorized to perform action: Invalid key' for POST request in chrome extension

Tags: rally

I developed a chrome extension using Rally's WSAPI v2.0, and it basically does the following things:

1. get user and project, and store them
2. get current iteration everytime
3. **send a post request to create a workitem**

For the THIRD step, I sometimes get error **["Not authorized to perform action: Invalid key"]** since end of last month.

[updated]**Error can be reproduced everytime if I log in Rally website via SSO before using the extension to send requests via apikey.** 
**What's the best practice to send subsequent requests via apikey in my extension** since I can't control end users' habits?

I did see some similar posts but none of them is helpful... and in case it helps:

- I'm adding ZSESSIONID:apikey in my request header, instead of user /
  password to authenticate, so I believe no security token is needed
  (https://comm.support.ca.com/kb/api-key-and-oauth-client-faq/kb000011568)
- url starts with https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/
- issue is fixed after clearing cookies for
  https://rally1.rallydev.com/, but somehow it appears again some time
  later
- I checked the cookie when the issue was reproduced, and found one with name of ZSESSIONID and its value became something else rather than the apikey. Not sure if that matters though...
- code for request:

```js
function initXHR(method, url, apikey, cbFunc) {
  let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ...
  httpRequest.open(method, url);
  httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', ' application\/json');
  httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Accept', ' application\/json');
  httpRequest.setRequestHeader('ZSESSIONID', apikey);
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    ...
    };
  return httpRequest;
}
...
usReq = initXHR ('POST', baseURL+'hierarchicalrequirement/create', apikey, function(){...});
```

Anyone has any idea / suggestion? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error when the API key had both read-only and full-access grants configured.  I would start by making sure your key only has the full-access grant.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I checked the apikey, only full-access is checked.

Comment: Hello David, just find that error can be reproduced everytime if I log in Rally website via SSO before using the extension to send requests via apikey. What's the best practice to send subsequent requests via apikey in my extension since I can't control end users' habits? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had almost exactly the same use case and similar experience, and this is how I resolved it.

If you are adding the API key in your header as `ZSESSIONID` (and based on your update, you are), this should work for you: In `fetch` request I added an option `credentials: "omit"`, which basically forced the request to avoid cached `ZSESSIONID` from SSO setup after being logged in already: and simply worked!

As you are using `XMLHttpRequest` approach, in your case it should most likely be `xhr.withCredentials = false`, but I did not test that one.